# Is fabric CrashLytics appropriate for released Applications?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-library

I am developping an Application that manipulates a lot of images and i am using [Fabric Crashlytics](https://fabric.io) (a library that report App bugs using internet) in debug mode. I want to know if i have to compile Crashlytics in the release version too. is it appropriate ? I am worrying about my App users and memory over-use

Comment: If you want to use that with release it should be there inside dependencies

Comment: yes it's ok, I've used fabric but now I'm using firebase and I think it's better than fabric

Comment: Thanks, but Google just acquired fabric in order to take full advantage of fabric crashlytics in firebase.